@Autowire on singleton bean in class field and method parameter gives different instances
Please take a look at code below:
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Slf4j
class BeanScopeTestController {

    private final SingletonBean singletonBean1;

    @Autowired
    BeanScopeTestController(SingletonBean singletonBean) {
        this.singletonBean1 = singletonBean;
    }
    
    @GetMapping
    String checkTheSameInstance(@Autowired SingletonBean singletonBean2) {
        log.info(singletonBean1.toString());
        log.info(singletonBean2.toString());
        boolean methodEquals = singletonBean1.equals(singletonBean2);
        boolean instanceEquals = singletonBean1 == singletonBean2;
        return String.format("method equals: %s; instance equals: %s", methodEquals, instanceEquals);
    }

}

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Slf4j
@Component
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
class SingletonBean {

    private static int idProvider = 0;
    private final int id;

    public SingletonBean() {
        this.id = idProvider++;
    }
    
}

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

How it is possible that the output of GET /test endpoint (method BeanScopeTestController#checkTheSameInstance) is method equals: false; instance equals: false?
Default scope for spring @Bean is Singleton to I would expect that class field singletonBean1 and method parameter singletonBean2 would get the same instance from Spring container, but those references are autowired with different instances of SingletonBean. Does @Autowire on method parameter in Spring MVC work differently so maybe bean scope is somehow overriden then? Or the reason of that is different?
I expected to have the same instance of SingletonBean autowired by class field and method parameter.

Are you sure it is 2 different instances. Spring uses proxy objects that wrap spring beans. In your case it may be 2 proxies pointing to the singleton. If you set a log or breakpoint in the constructor of your singleton, how many times it gets called?

@silver_mx I did set a breakpoint in the constructor and this breakpoint is hit 2 times. First time, at the startup of the Spring application, second time when I hit the /test endpoint. To depict this I implemented id field in SingletonBean that is incremented every time the constructor is called. And singletonBean1 class field has an instance with id = 0, but singletonBean2 method parameter gets an instance with id = 1 so for sure those are different instances.

And of course every time I hit /test endpoint new instance with new id is injected to a method mapped to this endpoint.

Ok, I think I know the answer. As per Spring MVC documentation:
Using @ModelAttribute is optional. By default, any parameter that is not a simple value type as determined by BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty AND that is not resolved by any other argument resolver is treated as an implicit @ModelAttribute.
So my SingletonBean injected to a method is treated as a @ModelAttribute. The docs about this are Method Arguments at the very bottom of the table and @ModelAttribute the Tip at the bottom of the page.
And next, @ModelAttribute has a request scope as can be deducted from below statement:
You can use the @ModelAttribute annotation:
On a method argument in @RequestMapping methods to create or access an Object from the model and to bind it to the request through a WebDataBinder.
That can be found in Model docs.

@Autowired simply doesn't work on a request mapping method as it isn't intended for that, so it is simply ignored and thus treated as a model attribute.
